# creating a dict from list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks something like this->

```
  list =  [{"id":1,"path":"a/b", ........},
           {"id":2,"path":"a/b/c", ........},
           {"id":3,"path":"a/b/c/d", ........}]
```

Now I want to create a dict of path to id mapping.
That should look something like this->

```
   d=dict()
   d["a/b"] = 1
   d["a/b/c"] = 2
   d["a/b/c/d"] = 3
```

how to create it in pythonic way

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
d = {i['path']:i['id'] for i in list}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
d = {x["path"]: x["id"] for x in list_of_dicts}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe?

```
list =  [{"id":1,"path":"a/b", "test":"1"},{"id":2,"path":"a/b/c", "test":"2"}, {"id":3,"path":"a/b/c/d", "test":"3"}]
d={}
for i in list:
    d[i['path']]=d['id']
print d
```

This is the output:

> {'a/b/c': 2, 'a/b/c/d': 3, 'a/b': 1}

Answer (score 0):

```
_lst =  [{"id":1,"path":"a/b"},
           {"id":2,"path":"a/b/c"},
           {"id":3,"path":"a/b/c/d"}]

d = {i["path"]: i["id"] for i in _lst}

print(d)
print(d["a/b"])
print(d["a/b/c"])
print(d["a/b/c/d"])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'a/b': 1, 'a/b/c': 2, 'a/b/c/d': 3}
1
2
3
```